# Symfony 1.4: Deleting a sfGuardUser

Tags: mysql, symfony1, foreign-keys, constraints, symfony-1.4

I'm having some trouble with the following...

I have a sfGuardUser table set up normally, and it has a one-to-one relationship with a Profile table, which contains some additional user info.

When a user wants to delete themselves from the site, I'd like to retain their info in the Profile table for various purposes BUT delete the sfGuardUser in order to keep that table cleaner/shorter (not just set it to inactive).

I was under the impression that I could set the FK in the Profile table to NULL and then delete the sfGuardUser, but it seems the FK-constraint fails.

Other than leaving outdated sfGuardUsers and Profiles in both of these tables, or having to use a cascaded delete to get rid of both, can anyone tell me if there's any other way around this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

Doctrine allows `onDelete: SET NULL.`

Hope that helps someone.